# Getting highscore for snake game from .txt file

Tags: java, eclipse

```
private int score = 0;
private int highScore = 0;


    private void gameOver(Graphics g) {

         try{
                PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Videvik\\workspace\\madu\\logi1.txt", true));
                writer.println(score);              
                writer.close();
                } catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}//creates .txt file

          File file = new File("logi1.txt");

            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                String line = reader.readLine();
                while (line != null)                 // read the score file line by line
                {
                    try {
                        int score2 = Integer.parseInt(line.trim());   // parse each line as an int
                        if (score2 > highScore)                       // and keep track of the largest
                        { 
                            highScore = score; 
                        }
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e1) {
                        // ignore invalid scores
                        //System.err.println("ignoring invalid score: " + line);
                    }
                    line = reader.readLine();
                }
                reader.close();

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.err.println("ERROR reading scores from file");


        String msg = "Game over!";//works
        String msg2 = "Points: "+score;//works
        String msg3 = "MaxPoints: "+highScore;//does not work

        Font small = new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 14);
        FontMetrics metr = getFontMetrics(small);

        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.setFont(small);
        g.drawString(msg, (B_WIDTH - metr.stringWidth(msg)) / 2, B_HEIGHT / 2);
        g.drawString(msg2, (B_WIDTH - metr.stringWidth(msg2)) / 4, B_HEIGHT / 4);
        g.drawString(msg3, (B_WIDTH - metr.stringWidth(msg3)) / 6, B_HEIGHT / 6);


            } 

    }
```

Well my problem is that I cant print out maximum score on screen from .txt file.  First program creates .txt file where all scores are saved(it works). Second function after that should find higest score from there and draw it out(does not work).(It draws out "Points" and "Game over!") Eclipse dont show any errors in code. What do I do wrong? I have to fix this thing for next Wednesday or I fail exam lol

Comment: Please only show the relevant parts of your code - it's quite daunting when a question has this many lines. Consider editing to make the question more concise

Comment: Yes, my fault, I took off unimportant parts.

Answer (score 0):

I think the potential errors are those two:

One path is absolute and the other is relative. FileWriter is accepting File as a Parameter, so why don't you use your "file" for both the reader and the writer? This way you would be sure they point to the same place.

Also look into if your Highscore is actually updated somewhere. It will also never show 0 as highscore otherwise you would need to change:

```
if(highscore2 > highscore)
```

to

```
if(highscore2 >= highscore)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you very much that solved my problem. Also other problem in that code was "score2" that was supposed to be just a "score" I don't know what I was thinking when I wrote that number 2 there.